# How to convert Longitude and Latitude to (Address/physical) in Leaflet HTML

Tags: html, leaflet, angular-leaflet-directive, leaflet.markercluster

This is my html script code:

```
for (var i = 0; i < planes.length; i++) {
    marker = new L.marker([planes[i][2],planes[i][3]], {icon: option}).addTo(map);
    marker.bindPopup('Employee: ' + planes[i][0] + '<br>Department: ' + planes[i][1] + '<br>Date Log: ' + planes[i][4]).addTo(map);     
}
```

I want to put an address in the `bindPopup('Employee: ' + planes[i][0] + '<br>Department: ' + planes[i][1] + '<br>Date Log: ' + planes[i][4] + 'Location : ' + ???)` like this one. So I am using longitude and latitude it can possibly get the address of the said coordinates. But my question is how? any links or advice will do. I'm only a freshman Cheers!

Comment: why the `PHP` tag?

Comment: sorry about that

Comment: What you are looking for I would suggest is called `GeoCoding` and, though I have never used `LeafletJS` they offer a [Geocoding service](https://leafletjs.com/plugins.html#geocoding). From the description: `"External services that transform an address or the name of a place into latitude and longitude (or vice versa)"`

Comment: i already searched about geocoding but they didn't uses long,lat for the address all they do is search using textbox or tapping the map :(

Comment: the `"Leaflet Control Geocoder"` ~ `A clean and extensible control for both geocoding and reverse geocoding` seems appropriate to your needs